# C++ alias for sin to std::sin - need sloppy quick-fix

Tags: c++, function, c++11, namespaces, alias

I've got a client trying to compile on an out of date compiler that doesn't seem to have std::sin and std::cos from c++11. (and they can't upgrade)
I'm looking for some kind of quick-fix to slap into the top of the header to make std::sin point to sin etc.
I've been trying things like

```
#ifndef std::sin
something something
namespace std{
point sin to outside sin
point cos to outside cos
};
#endif
```

but I haven't had any luck

any tips?
thanks

Comment: `#define std` horrible I know.

Comment: @john, the std namespace exists, but the c++11 versions of sin and cos aren't inside it. They only have the old versions, which are outside the namespace.

Comment: `std::sin` and `std::cos` are not from C++11, they have been part of C++ since ever. Just include `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>`. If that comment is rubbish, then please make the question more specific what it actually is that this *"out of date compiler"* lacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, it should work to use

```
#include <math.h>
namespace std {
    using ::sin;
    using ::cos;
}
```

Some of these functions are, however, implemented in a funny way and you might need to use something like this instead:

```
#include <math.h>
namespace std {
    inline float       sin(float f)        { return ::sinf(f); }
    inline double      sin(double d)       { return ::sin(d); }
    inline long double sin(long double ld) { return ::sinl(ld); }
    inline float       cos(float f)        { return ::cosf(f); }
    inline double      cos(double d)       { return ::cos(d); }
    inline long double cos(long double ld) { return ::cosl(ld); }
}
```

Note that neither of these approach is portable and they may or may not work. Also, note that you can't test for `std::sin` being defined: You'll need to set up a suitable macro name.

Comment: thx, I went with the latter and just did the floats for sin and cos :)

Comment: Wouldn't you get a multiple definition error on compilers that do have these functions in the std namespace already?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a reference to the function like so...

```
#include <math.h>
namespace std
{
    typedef double (&sinfunc)(double);
    static const sinfunc sin = ::sin;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't pollute the std namespace but the following might work:

```
struct MYLIB_double {
    double v_;
    MYLIB_double (double v) : v_(v) {}
};

namespace std {
   inline double sin(MYLIB_double d) {
        return sin(d.v_);
   }
}
```

If '`sin`' exists in namespace std, the it will be directly called with arguments of `double`.  If it doesn't then the value will be implicitly converted to '`MYLIB_double`' and the overload will be called which will call `sin` in either the `std` or (since `std::sin(double)` doesn't exist), the global namespace.  You might need overloads for float etc.

Another probably better suggestion would be to add a conditional that they can use:

```
#ifdef MYLIB_NO_STD_SIN
namespace std {
   inline double sin(double x) {
        return ::sin(x);
   }
}
#endif
```